# pass variable from one method to another within the same controller

Tags: php, laravel

I found similar topic but none fixed my problem.

I have method in controller and try to use variable in another method but within same Controller.

That's my 1st method:

```
 public function show($id)
{
    $specification = RegenerationsSpecification::with('regenerations', 'user')
        ->findOrFail($id);
    return Fractal::item($specification, ['regenerations.specialist', 'regenerations.department', 'regenerations.patient', 'user']);
}
```

and then I try to pass `$specification` to another function like this:

```
    public function exportToExcel()
{
        $spec[] = $this->show($specification);
        return $spec;
}
```

I dont know what I'm doing wrong, but it doesnt pass `$specification` variable.

Anyone could help me here?
Thank you

Comment: `$specification` is not defined in `exportToExcel()`. Maybe you can initialize it into a class property instead? Where are you calling `exportToExcel()`?

Comment: in your show function you have to add that variable to access it in show method like this. `public function show($specification, $id)`

Comment: If export to excel had an id as a parameter, you could get specification as in the show function.

Comment: Define  $specification  first in  exportToExcel function

Comment: @Yogendrasinh it shows now that's unused parameter in show method

Comment: @Mozammil I want to call this method in view where show $specification collection to export this collection to excel file

Comment: @RahulKalal I want to define it by calling from previous function which is show()

Comment: @Kusy ok then in show function just change like this show($id='') hope it work

Comment: @Kusy Is there any route that triggers the `exportToExcel()` method?

Comment: well, Im using angularJS with Laravel, so that's Route for show(): @Get("api/specifications/details/{id}") and that's the one for exportToExcel(): * @Post("api/specifications/xls"). I run this method under button in view where show() is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
  public function show($id)
 {
    $specification = 
    RegenerationsSpecification::with('regenerations', 'user')
    ->findOrFail($id);
    Session::set('specification', $specification );
    return Fractal::item($specification, ['regenerations.specialist', 
    'regenerations.department', 'regenerations.patient', 'user']);
 }

 public function exportToExcel()
 {
    specification =array();
    if(Session::has('specification')) 
      $specification = Session::get('specification'); 
    }
    $spec[] = $specification;
    return $spec;
 }
```

Comment: gives me undefined variable

Answer (score 0):

You need to make $specification variable global. as You want to share this variable in your methods;

```
class DirectNegotiationController extends Controller
{
  protected $specification;


     public function show($id)
    {
        $this->specification = RegenerationsSpecification::with('regenerations', 'user')
            ->findOrFail($id);
        return Fractal::item($this->specification, ['regenerations.specialist', 'regenerations.department', 'regenerations.patient', 'user']);
    }

    public function exportToExcel()
    {
            $spec[] = $this->show($this->specification);
            return $spec;
    }



}
```

Comment: gives me undefined variable

Comment: "No query results for model [App\Models\Specifications\RegenerationsSpecification]."

Comment: dont know why, I want use item $specification from previous method

Comment: The $id you pass not available in your datatable RegenerationsSpecification table.

Comment: actually it is the id from  RegenerationsSpecification table, how i can pass it to the 2nd method?

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
//public function exportToExcel($specification)
public function exportToExcel($specification=0)
{
        $spec[] = $this->show($specification);
        return $spec;
}
```

First method remains unchanged:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $specification = RegenerationsSpecification::with('regenerations', 'user')
        ->findOrFail($id);
    return Fractal::item($specification, ['regenerations.specialist', 'regenerations.department', 'regenerations.patient', 'user']);
}
```

Comment: Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\RegenerationsSpecificationsController::exportToExcel(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected

Comment: That means the route is calling the function with no parameter

Comment: I have updated the code to pass the error, but you still need to ensure a parameter is passed.

Comment: it doesnt work for me, i dont know how to pass $id also to exportToExcel function.. I think this would solve my issue

Comment: You must pass it through Angular, as you mentioned: @Get("api/specifications/details/{id}")